# : jsRoute tag not found

Tags: playframework

Code:

var showBookPagination = #{jsRoute @Controller.methodName(':id')/};

Error thrown:

Template not found (In /app/views/ReaderController/browse.html around line 56)
The template tags/jsRoute.html or tags/jsRoute.tag does not exist.

**Any idea on this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what the problem was... It was reported as a bug Bug #512073. And till today the website has not been changed. The correct should be:

var showBookPagination = #{jsAction @Controller.methodName(':id')/};